# Remembering color-choice through Jquery (localStorage)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a very simple and basic Jquery script that changes the class for textboxes on my site in order for them to have a different colored background when a button is clicked. I then attempted (with the help of a Jquery-for-dummies-book) to set it up so that the color choice is remembered locally.

I must however be a greater "dummy" than expected because I have not been able to make this work.When I upload the script to the server and test it on the site, I can change the color, but if I close then window and then go to my website again, the color is back to default. It is NOT remembered/stored.

Is it possible the problem stems from the fact that my textboxes use the class "row" to set the background color, and you can not change a class to a different class, but must use a proper element or ID? Or should the order of the script-parts perhaps be different? 
Any and all insight is appreciated on my learning-journey.

External script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (localStorage.getItem("farvevalg")=="farve") { $(".row").addClass("farve");
  }

  if ($(".row").hasClass("farve")) {
    localStorage.setItem("farvevalg", "farve");
  } else {localStorage.removeItem("farvevalg")}

  $('#farvevalg').click(function(){
      $(".row").toggleClass('farve');
    }); }
```

My HTML

```
/*The default color of all textboxes on a page*/
.row {background-color: #e7e7e7;}

/*The color that it changes into when button is clicked*/
.farve {background-color: pink;}

/*The button that must be clicked to change color*/
#farvevalg {
    margin-top: 6%;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: "farge" and "fargevalg" are not English. Always code in English. When including code in a question make sure it is in English.

Comment: Oh, thank you for pointing that out.  Is this a general "best pratice" rule or a rule for questions on StackOverflow I have missed? I have always used my own language for specific class-names but me and my fellow amateur coding-buddies all speak the same native language, so we have never dicussed wether or not one should use english for class-names and ID´s or not.

Comment: It is a best practice for both programming in general and StackOverflow. When coding something, others might need to collaborate and might maintain that code you wrote, even people who don't speak English. When asking a question on StackOverflow, it makes it easier for people to understand your code if its written in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt is correct but add/remove localStorage you are doing at the wrong place. You should do it inside that button click.

[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7r31ptgL/2/)

**Snippet won't work because of the CORS issue. It's for code view only.**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

              if (localStorage.getItem("farvevalg") == "farve") {
                $(".row").addClass("farve");
              }


              $('#farvevalg').click(function () {
                $(".row").toggleClass('farve');
                if ($(".row").hasClass("farve")) {
                  localStorage.setItem("farvevalg", "farve");
                } else {
                  localStorage.removeItem("farvevalg")
                }
              });
            });
```

```css
/*The default color of all textboxes on a page*/
.row {background-color: #e7e7e7;}

/*The color that it changes into when button is clicked*/
.farve {background-color: pink;}

/*The button that must be clicked to change color*/
#farvevalg {
    margin-top: 6%;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
Test
</div>
<button id="farvevalg">
Change
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

some changes in login, not tested but should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if (localStorage.getItem("farvevalg")=="farve") { 

        $(".row").addClass("farve");
    }


    $('#farvevalg').click(function(){
//only here we add/remove setting
        var wasFarveColor = $(".row").hasClass("farve")

        $(".row").toggleClass('farve');

        if(wasFarveColor)
            localStorage.removeItem("farvevalg")
        else
            localStorage.setItem("farvevalg", "farve")

      }); 
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is, at the start of your application, check it there is a saved item 'farvevalg' with value 'farve'. If that is the case, then you add the class 'farve' to all elements with class 'row'.
After this you check if there is a row element with class 'farve' and, if that is the case' you set the item in storage, otherwise you delete it. As you can see it doesn't make sense for this bit of code to be here as it won't have any effect. You should instead move this if/else block inside of the click callback ( after `$(".row").toggleClass('farve');` )